# Derivation of a slang greeting in Yorkshire: "Aye up serry"

Tags: etymology, slang, greetings, british-english

When I was young, in the West Riding of Yorkshire 1942 to 1960 you would greet an acquaintance thus: "Aye up serry". I believe older residents of the village of Kiveton Park still use the phrase, or one like it identifying the object of the remark as 'serry'. I wonder if this could be traced back to 'sirrah', a 16th century 'corruption' of 'sire'. Can anyone shed light on this?

Comment: Are you asking about 'aye up' ('a slang greeting'), or 'serry', HL42?

Comment: Thank you for asking! It does resemble *sirrah* or other offshoots of *sir*.  There is the related expression *Ey up mi duck*, including [a book on dialect](https://www.google.com/search?q=Ey+Up+Mi+Duck&client=firefox-b-1-d&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjKqafSjtPjAhUBSN8KHdj2D4oQ_AUIFygB&biw=1252&bih=600) by that title (written by Richard Scollins, ‎John Titford, published in 2000). The "duck" likely relates to *duke*, so by analogy *serry* ~ *sir* makes sense. I wish I could be of more help.

Comment: Also, the forum post here may be informative about *serry*: https://nottstalgia.com/forums/topic/10208-serry/

Comment: 'Serry' is, or at least was in the 50s and 60s, common in Derbyshire as well. The interesting thing is that many of us could make perfect sense of Shakespearean and Biblical English because our native dialect was pretty much unchanged from the 16th century; since I was old enough to think about it I've always considered "serry" to be a surviving form of "sirrah". Having said that I'm less convinced by the derivation of "duck" from "duke" since "duck" is a term of endearment rather than respect, usually used to address children and members of the opposite sex, apparently closer to "chick".

Comment: _Ey up mi duck_ was originally self-published in several parts in 1976. I agree with @BoldBen about 'sirrah' and 'duck'. My late father (who didn't speak dialect except occasionally in fun) used to call me 'duck'.

Comment: I think it's highly likely. Useful somewhat: UrbanDictionary definition 2: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Serry

Answer (score 4):

According to [The Voice of England's Past](https://www.nytimes.com/1984/07/08/travel/the-voice-of-englands-past.html) *New York Times* 8 July 1984 by [Paul West](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_West_(writer)) of Derbyshire, England:

> "Eigh-up, serry," they call out to you, as to one another, meaning: I have noticed you, sirrah (an Elizabethan word).

[I, Said the Sparrow](https://books.google.com/books?id=wCUkAAAAMAAJ&q=editors%20%22who%20knew%20what%20the%20local%20greeting,%20'Eigh-up,%20serry',%20meant.%20%22&dq=editors%20%22who%20knew%20what%20the%20local%20greeting,%20'Eigh-up,%20serry',%20meant.%20%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjI44KMtNjlAhUBT98KHfDpDJYQ6AEwAHoECAAQAg) (1963), also by Paul West, is the oldest mention of the phrase that I found and says:

> [page 82] 'Thee' and 'thou' are common forms of address; you always address a male interlocutor as 'serry' (which really brought to life for me the Elizabethan 'sirrah')

and

> [page 87] He must have been one of the few literary editors who knew what the local greeting, 'Eigh-up, serry', meant.

Also, according to the 1920 [Dialect of the Staffordshire Moorlands](https://books.google.com/books?id=XIQ1AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA185&dq=%22greeting%22%20%22sirrah%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiG_PXdydjlAhVopVkKHVLrBBYQ6AEwAHoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q=%22greeting%22%20%22sirrah%22&f=false) *Transactions and Annual Report of the Staffordshire Field Club*, volume LIV, pages 44-53,

> The farm lad is still sirrah (pronounced surrey)

...

> The common greeting among the young farm-hands (male) is “ How go, sirrah ? ” This, of course, is common enough in Shakespeare's time, *cf*. Ah, sirrah ” (*As You Like It*, iv, 3), and “ Sirrah begone ” (Marlowe, *Edward II*, v, 2).

Comment: Best answer yet, partly because you were able to get to an alternate spelling for "aye" or "ey" that appeared in earlier sources.

Answer (score 0):

My father, born 1908, used this expression all his life. I remember discussing it in an English lesson(circa 1959)and coming to the conclusion that it’s a left over version of the Shakesperian/Elizabethan “sirrah”, - sir.

Comment: "Coming to the conclusion" how? You omitted the most relevant part.

Answer (score 0):

OED:

> **sirrah, n.**
>     Brit. /ˈsɪrə/
>   ,  U.S. /ˈsɪrə/
>
> Forms:  α. 15 syra, syrra ( syrria?), 15–16 sirra. β. 15 syrha, syrrha, 15–16 sirha, sirrha. γ. 15 sirah, 16 surrah, syrrah, 16– sirrah. δ. 15 serea, serrha, 18 dialect serrah.

As can be seen, the spelling is inconsistent as it is merely an attempt to replicate a dialect. In Derbyshire, it is pronounced /ˈsʌrɛ<sup>h</sup>/ (or /ˈsʌri/, with the possibility that the /i/ (here and in other dialects) is a (patronising or affectionate) diminutive.

Answer (score 0):

In a South Derbyshire pit village (Castle Gresley) in the fifties, "eh up, sorry" was a standard dialect greeting. The customary response was "sorry-ah". For a time, at Ashby Grammar School, we affected this, to reflect our general savoir-faire and worldliness.